# Linq To SQL :Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown,how i can correct this error?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, linq-to-sql

i am trying to retrieve the data from the server with Linq ,there are about 167 records in this table but when i compile the code i receive always this error :

```
Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown .
```

Here i post the code that i use(using LinqPad) :

```
var query1 = from c in TOUR_SIC_COST_ZEROs where c.ID ==2

                   select
                       new
                       {
                           c.ID,
                           c.Code,
                           c.CountryCode,
                           c.ProductTypeList,
                           c.KindOfTour00,
                           c.KindOfTour01,
                           c.KindOfTour02,
                           c.ClientName,
                           c.Status,
                           c.CurrencyCode,
                           c.TitleTour,
                                 c.ItalianDay1,
                              c.ItalianDay2,
                              c.ItalianDay3,
                              c.ItalianDay4,
                              c.ItalianDay5,
                              c.ItalianDay6,
                              c.ItalianDay7,
                              c.ItalianDay8,
                              c.ItalianDay9,
                              c.ItalianDay10,
                              c.ItalianDay11,
                              c.ItalianDay12,
                              c.ItalianDay13,
                              c.ItalianDay14,
                              c.ItalianDay15,
                              c.ItalianDay16,
                              c.ItalianDay17,
                              c.ItalianDay18,
                              c.ItalianDay19,
                              c.ItalianDay20,
                              c.EnglishDay1,
                              c.EnglishDay2,
                              c.EnglishDay3,
                              c.EnglishDay4,
                              c.EnglishDay5,
                              c.EnglishDay6,
                              c.EnglishDay7,
                              c.EnglishDay8,
                              c.EnglishDay9,
                              c.EnglishDay10,
                              c.EnglishDay11,
                              c.EnglishDay12,
                              c.EnglishDay13,
                              c.EnglishDay14,
                              c.EnglishDay15,
                              c.EnglishDay16,
                              c.EnglishDay17,
                              c.EnglishDay18,
                              c.EnglishDay19,
                              c.EnglishDay20,
                              c.FrenchDay1,
                              c.FrenchDay2,
                              c.FrenchDay3,
                              c.FrenchDay4,
                              c.FrenchDay5,
                              c.FrenchDay6,
                              c.FrenchDay7,
                              c.FrenchDay8,
                              c.FrenchDay9,
                              c.FrenchDay10,
                              c.FrenchDay11,
                              c.FrenchDay12,
                              c.FrenchDay13,
                              c.FrenchDay14,
                              c.FrenchDay15,
                              c.FrenchDay16,
                              c.FrenchDay17,
                              c.FrenchDay18,
                              c.FrenchDay19,
                              c.FrenchDay20,
                              c.SpanishDay1,
                              c.SpanishDay2,
                              c.SpanishDay3,
                              c.SpanishDay4,
                              c.SpanishDay5,
                              c.SpanishDay6,
                              c.SpanishDay7,
                              c.SpanishDay8,
                              c.SpanishDay9,
                              c.SpanishDay10,
                              c.SpanishDay11,
                              c.SpanishDay12,
                              c.SpanishDay13,
                              c.SpanishDay14,
                              c.SpanishDay15,
                              c.SpanishDay16,
                              c.SpanishDay17,
                              c.SpanishDay18,
                              c.SpanishDay19,
                              c.SpanishDay20,

                        /*   c._1Pax_Del,
                           c._2Pax_Del,
                           c._3_5Pax_Del,
                           c._6_9Pax_Del,
                           c._10_14Pax_Del,
                           c._15_19Pax_Del,
                           c._20_29Pax_Del,
                           c._30_40Pax_Del,
                           c._Sup_SGL_Del,
                           c._Red_3rd_pers_Del,
                           c._1Pax_Sup,
                           c._2Pax_Sup,
                           c._3_5Pax_Sup,
                           c._6_9Pax_Sup,
                           c._10_14Pax_Sup,
                           c._15_19Pax_Sup,
                           c._20_29Pax_Sup,
                           c._30_40Pax_Sup,
                           c._Sup_SGL_Sup,
                           c._Red_3rd_pers_Sup,
                           c._1Pax_1Cat,
                           c._2Pax_1Cat,
                           c._3_5Pax_1Cat,
                           c._6_9Pax_1Cat,
                           c._10_14Pax_1Cat,
                           c._15_19Pax_1Cat,
                           c._20_29Pax_1Cat,
                           c._30_40Pax_1Cat,
                           c._Sup_SGL_1Cat,
                           c._Red_3rd_pers_1Cat,
                           c._1Pax_Smart,
                           c._2Pax_Smart,
                           c._3_5Pax_Smart,
                           c._6_9Pax_Smart,
                           c._10_14Pax_Smart,
                           c._15_19Pax_Smart,
                           c._20_29Pax_Smart,
                           c._30_40Pax_Smart,
                           c._Sup_SGL_Smart,
                           c._Red_3rd_pers_Smart,
                           c._1Pax_Mixed,
                           c._2Pax_Mixed,
                           c._3_5Pax_Mixed,
                           c._6_9Pax_Mixed,
                           c._10_14Pax_Mixed,
                           c._15_19Pax_Mixed,
                           c._20_29Pax_Mixed,
                           c._30_40Pax_Mixed,
                           c._Sup_SGL_Mixed,
                           c._Red_3rd_pers_Mixed,
                           c._1Pax_Tailor,
                           c._2Pax_Tailor,
                           c._3_5Pax_Tailor,
                           c._6_9Pax_Tailor,
                           c._10_14Pax_Tailor,
                           c._15_19Pax_Tailor,
                           c._20_29Pax_Tailor,
                           c._30_40Pax_Tailor,
                           c._Sup_SGL_Tailor,
                           c._Red_3rd_pers_Tailor,
                           c.Promotion_1,
                           c.Promotion1_ValidFrom,
                           c.Promotion1_ValidTo,
                           c.PromotionFormula1,
                           c.PromotionRoomPerc_1,
                           c.PromotionRoomPrice_1,
                           c.IsDecrease_1,
                           c.IsIncrease_1,
                           c.IsDefault_1,
                           c.Promotion_2,
                           c.Promotion2_ValidFrom,
                           c.Promotion2_ValidTo,
                           c.PromotionFormula2,
                           c.PromotionRoomPerc_2,
                           c.PromotionRoomPrice_2,
                           c.IsDecrease_2,
                           c.IsIncrease_2,
                           c.IsDefault_2,
                           c.Promotion_3,
                           c.Promotion3_ValidFrom,
                           c.Promotion3_ValidTo,
                           c.PromotionFormula3,
                           c.PromotionRoomPerc_3,
                           c.PromotionRoomPrice_3,
                           c.IsDecrease_3,
                           c.IsIncrease_3,
                           c.IsDefault_3,
                           c.Promotion_4,
                           c.Promotion4_ValidFrom,
                           c.Promotion4_ValidTo,
                           c.PromotionFormula4,
                           c.PromotionRoomPerc_4,
                           c.PromotionRoomPrice_4,
                           c.IsDecrease_4,
                           c.IsIncrease_4,
                           c.IsDefault_4,
                           c.Promotion_5,
                           c.Promotion5_ValidFrom,
                           c.Promotion5_ValidTo,
                           c.PromotionFormula5,
                           c.PromotionRoomPerc_5,
                           c.PromotionRoomPrice_5,
                           c.IsDecrease_5,
                           c.IsIncrease_5,
                           c.IsDefault_5,
                           c.Promotion_6,
                           c.Promotion6_ValidFrom,
                           c.Promotion6_ValidTo,
                           c.PromotionFormula6,
                           c.PromotionRoomPerc_6,
                           c.PromotionRoomPrice_6,
                           c.IsDecrease_6,
                           c.IsIncrease_6,
                           c.IsDefault_6,
                           c.Promotion_7,
                           c.Promotion7_ValidFrom,
                           c.Promotion7_ValidTo,
                           c.PromotionFormula7,
                           c.PromotionRoomPerc_7,
                           c.PromotionRoomPrice_7,
                           c.IsDecrease_7,
                           c.IsIncrease_7,
                           c.IsDefault_7,*/
                           c.CityCode1,
                           c.CityCode2,
                           c.CityCode3,
                           c.CityCode4,
                           c.CityCode5,
                           c.CityCode6,
                           c.CityCode7,
                           c.CityCode8,
                           c.CityCode9,
                           c.CityCode10,
                           c.CityCode11,

                           c.Note,
                           c.UserCreated,
                           c.DateCreated,
                           c.UserModified,
                           c.DateModified
                       };
                       var query2 = from c in TOUR_SIC_COST_ZEROs where c.ID==2 
                       select new 
                       {
                       c.ID,
                        c._1Pax_Del,
                           c._2Pax_Del,
                           c._3_5Pax_Del,
                           c._6_9Pax_Del,
                           c._10_14Pax_Del,
                           c._15_19Pax_Del,
                           c._20_29Pax_Del,
                           c._30_40Pax_Del,
                           c._Sup_SGL_Del,
                           c._Red_3rd_pers_Del,
                           c._1Pax_Sup,
                           c._2Pax_Sup,
                           c._3_5Pax_Sup,
                           c._6_9Pax_Sup,
                           c._10_14Pax_Sup,
                           c._15_19Pax_Sup,
                           c._20_29Pax_Sup,
                           c._30_40Pax_Sup,
                           c._Sup_SGL_Sup,
                           c._Red_3rd_pers_Sup,
                           c._1Pax_1Cat,
                           c._2Pax_1Cat,
                           c._3_5Pax_1Cat,
                           c._6_9Pax_1Cat,
                           c._10_14Pax_1Cat,
                           c._15_19Pax_1Cat,
                           c._20_29Pax_1Cat,
                           c._30_40Pax_1Cat,
                           c._Sup_SGL_1Cat,
                           c._Red_3rd_pers_1Cat,
                           c._1Pax_Smart,
                           c._2Pax_Smart,
                           c._3_5Pax_Smart,
                           c._6_9Pax_Smart,
                           c._10_14Pax_Smart,
                           c._15_19Pax_Smart,
                           c._20_29Pax_Smart,
                           c._30_40Pax_Smart,
                           c._Sup_SGL_Smart,
                           c._Red_3rd_pers_Smart,
                           c._1Pax_Mixed,
                           c._2Pax_Mixed,
                           c._3_5Pax_Mixed,
                           c._6_9Pax_Mixed,
                           c._10_14Pax_Mixed,
                           c._15_19Pax_Mixed,
                           c._20_29Pax_Mixed,
                           c._30_40Pax_Mixed,
                           c._Sup_SGL_Mixed,
                           c._Red_3rd_pers_Mixed,
                           c._1Pax_Tailor,
                           c._2Pax_Tailor,
                           c._3_5Pax_Tailor,
                           c._6_9Pax_Tailor,
                           c._10_14Pax_Tailor,
                           c._15_19Pax_Tailor,
                           c._20_29Pax_Tailor,
                           c._30_40Pax_Tailor,
                           c._Sup_SGL_Tailor,
                           c._Red_3rd_pers_Tailor,
                       };
                       var total = from c in  query1 where c.ID == 2
                       from d in query2.Where(a =>a.ID == c.ID)
                       select new 
                       {

                        c.ID,
                           c.Code,
                           c.CountryCode,
                           c.ProductTypeList,
                           c.KindOfTour00,
                           c.KindOfTour01,
                           c.KindOfTour02,
                           c.ClientName,
                           c.Status,
                           c.CurrencyCode,
                           c.TitleTour,
                                 c.ItalianDay1,
                              c.ItalianDay2,
                              c.ItalianDay3,
                              c.ItalianDay4,
                              c.ItalianDay5,
                              c.ItalianDay6,
                              c.ItalianDay7,
                              c.ItalianDay8,
                              c.ItalianDay9,
                              c.ItalianDay10,
                              c.ItalianDay11,
                              c.ItalianDay12,
                              c.ItalianDay13,
                              c.ItalianDay14,
                              c.ItalianDay15,
                              c.ItalianDay16,
                              c.ItalianDay17,
                              c.ItalianDay18,
                              c.ItalianDay19,
                              c.ItalianDay20,
                              c.EnglishDay1,
                              c.EnglishDay2,
                              c.EnglishDay3,
                              c.EnglishDay4,
                              c.EnglishDay5,
                              c.EnglishDay6,
                              c.EnglishDay7,
                              c.EnglishDay8,
                              c.EnglishDay9,
                              c.EnglishDay10,
                              c.EnglishDay11,
                              c.EnglishDay12,
                              c.EnglishDay13,
                              c.EnglishDay14,
                              c.EnglishDay15,
                              c.EnglishDay16,
                              c.EnglishDay17,
                              c.EnglishDay18,
                              c.EnglishDay19,
                              c.EnglishDay20,
                              c.FrenchDay1,
                              c.FrenchDay2,
                              c.FrenchDay3,
                              c.FrenchDay4,
                              c.FrenchDay5,
                              c.FrenchDay6,
                              c.FrenchDay7,
                              c.FrenchDay8,
                              c.FrenchDay9,
                              c.FrenchDay10,
                              c.FrenchDay11,
                              c.FrenchDay12,
                              c.FrenchDay13,
                              c.FrenchDay14,
                              c.FrenchDay15,
                              c.FrenchDay16,
                              c.FrenchDay17,
                              c.FrenchDay18,
                              c.FrenchDay19,
                              c.FrenchDay20,
                              c.SpanishDay1,
                              c.SpanishDay2,
                              c.SpanishDay3,
                              c.SpanishDay4,
                              c.SpanishDay5,
                              c.SpanishDay6,
                              c.SpanishDay7,
                              c.SpanishDay8,
                              c.SpanishDay9,
                              c.SpanishDay10,
                              c.SpanishDay11,
                              c.SpanishDay12,
                              c.SpanishDay13,
                              c.SpanishDay14,
                              c.SpanishDay15,
                              c.SpanishDay16,
                              c.SpanishDay17,
                              c.SpanishDay18,
                              c.SpanishDay19,
                              c.SpanishDay20,

                      d._1Pax_Del,
                           d._2Pax_Del,
                           d._3_5Pax_Del,
                           d._6_9Pax_Del,
                           d._10_14Pax_Del,
                           d._15_19Pax_Del,
                           d._20_29Pax_Del,
                           d._30_40Pax_Del,
                           d._Sup_SGL_Del,
                           d._Red_3rd_pers_Del,
                           d._1Pax_Sup,
                           d._2Pax_Sup,
                           d._3_5Pax_Sup,
                           d._6_9Pax_Sup,
                           d._10_14Pax_Sup,
                           d._15_19Pax_Sup,
                           d._20_29Pax_Sup,
                           d._30_40Pax_Sup,
                           d._Sup_SGL_Sup,
                           d._Red_3rd_pers_Sup,
                           d._1Pax_1Cat,
                           d._2Pax_1Cat,
                           d._3_5Pax_1Cat,
                           d._6_9Pax_1Cat,
                           d._10_14Pax_1Cat,
                           d._15_19Pax_1Cat,
                           d._20_29Pax_1Cat,
                           d._30_40Pax_1Cat,
                           d._Sup_SGL_1Cat,
                           d._Red_3rd_pers_1Cat,
                           d._1Pax_Smart,
                           d._2Pax_Smart,
                           d._3_5Pax_Smart,
                           d._6_9Pax_Smart,
                           d._10_14Pax_Smart,
                           d._15_19Pax_Smart,
                           d._20_29Pax_Smart,
                           d._30_40Pax_Smart,
                           d._Sup_SGL_Smart,
                           d._Red_3rd_pers_Smart,
                           d._1Pax_Mixed,
                           d._2Pax_Mixed,
                           d._3_5Pax_Mixed,
                           d._6_9Pax_Mixed,
                           d._10_14Pax_Mixed,
                           d._15_19Pax_Mixed,
                           d._20_29Pax_Mixed,
                           d._30_40Pax_Mixed,
                           d._Sup_SGL_Mixed,
                           d._Red_3rd_pers_Mixed,
                           d._1Pax_Tailor,
                           d._2Pax_Tailor,
                           d._3_5Pax_Tailor,
                           d._6_9Pax_Tailor,
                           d._10_14Pax_Tailor,
                           d._15_19Pax_Tailor,
                           d._20_29Pax_Tailor,
                           d._30_40Pax_Tailor,
                           d._Sup_SGL_Tailor,
                           d._Red_3rd_pers_Tailor,
                        /*   c.Promotion_1,
                           c.Promotion1_ValidFrom,
                           c.Promotion1_ValidTo,
                           c.PromotionFormula1,
                           c.PromotionRoomPerc_1,
                           c.PromotionRoomPrice_1,
                           c.IsDecrease_1,
                           c.IsIncrease_1,
                           c.IsDefault_1,
                           c.Promotion_2,
                           c.Promotion2_ValidFrom,
                           c.Promotion2_ValidTo,
                           c.PromotionFormula2,
                           c.PromotionRoomPerc_2,
                           c.PromotionRoomPrice_2,
                           c.IsDecrease_2,
                           c.IsIncrease_2,
                           c.IsDefault_2,
                           c.Promotion_3,
                           c.Promotion3_ValidFrom,
                           c.Promotion3_ValidTo,
                           c.PromotionFormula3,
                           c.PromotionRoomPerc_3,
                           c.PromotionRoomPrice_3,
                           c.IsDecrease_3,
                           c.IsIncrease_3,
                           c.IsDefault_3,
                           c.Promotion_4,
                           c.Promotion4_ValidFrom,
                           c.Promotion4_ValidTo,
                           c.PromotionFormula4,
                           c.PromotionRoomPerc_4,
                           c.PromotionRoomPrice_4,
                           c.IsDecrease_4,
                           c.IsIncrease_4,
                           c.IsDefault_4,
                           c.Promotion_5,
                           c.Promotion5_ValidFrom,
                           c.Promotion5_ValidTo,
                           c.PromotionFormula5,
                           c.PromotionRoomPerc_5,
                           c.PromotionRoomPrice_5,
                           c.IsDecrease_5,
                           c.IsIncrease_5,
                           c.IsDefault_5,
                           c.Promotion_6,
                           c.Promotion6_ValidFrom,
                           c.Promotion6_ValidTo,
                           c.PromotionFormula6,
                           c.PromotionRoomPerc_6,
                           c.PromotionRoomPrice_6,
                           c.IsDecrease_6,
                           c.IsIncrease_6,
                           c.IsDefault_6,
                           c.Promotion_7,
                           c.Promotion7_ValidFrom,
                           c.Promotion7_ValidTo,
                           c.PromotionFormula7,
                           c.PromotionRoomPerc_7,
                           c.PromotionRoomPrice_7,
                           c.IsDecrease_7,
                           c.IsIncrease_7,
                           c.IsDefault_7,*/
                           c.CityCode1,
                           c.CityCode2,
                           c.CityCode3,
                           c.CityCode4,
                           c.CityCode5,
                           c.CityCode6,
                           c.CityCode7,
                           c.CityCode8,
                           c.CityCode9,
                           c.CityCode10,
                           c.CityCode11,

                           c.Note,
                           c.UserCreated,
                           c.DateCreated,
                           c.UserModified,
                           c.DateModified
                       };
                       total.Dump();
```

Do you have any idea how work out this step ?

Thanks so much for your attention.

Cheers

Comment: My Ohh My Did i miss a heart beat

Comment: I ran out of memory trying to read this...

Comment: @ Henk Holterman ,hahahahaha ,me too i wish ran out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

before using query1 and query2 in last query why dont you put `ToList()` method which might resolve your issue.....

```
var query1 = (from dad in data select d ).ToList();
```

Comment: ,yes it is right,thank so much for your very fast reply...have a nice day